# Java: Copy text to clipboard in a Apache Wicket web application

Tags: java, web-applications, wicket, clipboard

I am looking for a method to allow the user of my Wicket web application to copy the text of a Label into clipboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Wicketstuff ClipboardJS integration: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/wicket-7.x/wicketstuff-clipboard-js-parent

It uses https://clipboardjs.com.